# ElvUI health bars changes

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I haven't updated ElvUI for a few months. Now I had to do it because NPC's health bars didn't work at all (it showed standard wow bards instead).

But now, after update, ElvUI bars are back and I see two problems which are new to me:

1. Agro shown incorrectly: I see with Omen that my tank is keeping agro from all mobs, but Elv sometimes shows some of the bars red (This problem I noted a month ago, after 6.0.0 wow's patch and decided to postpone ElvUI update at that time, but unfortunately I can't postpone it now).
2. The health bar shows percent of the mob's health instead of the value.

Here is what I tried without success:

1. I tried to switch off and on health bars and agro colour display. This doesn't help.
2. I see in the options (Health indicators/health bars/fonts) that "current value" (not percent) is chosen, and that I can't really change it (the format menu is gray).

Comment: Patch 6.2.2 changed some things on the WoW side of the healthbar code. All addons have to be updated accordingly. You will have to wait a few hours / days until ElvUI is fixed.

Comment: @Raidri, how told you so? Check this out: http://www.tukui.org/changelog.php?ui=elvui there are already 2 versions of ElvUI, which "works for patch 6.2.0 and 6.2.2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I fixed this by disabling the option to change health bar colour when npc's health is low. It must be some bug, which forced ElvUI to ignore this option before and was fixed in the new patches.
2. This is intended thing. According to [ElvUI team](http://www.tukui.org/changelog.php?ui=elvui): Because of a change on Blizzards end we have to force the use of the "Percent" format for nameplate health text, at least for the time being.